# vb.net - Mysql connections are not closing using Sub routines

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-connection

I'm using the code below in a module that I can then call from anywhere else in the program to manage my `mysql database connection.`  I just call the dbExecute sub and then it in turn is supposed to open a DB connection using the `manageConnection(true)` statement and then close the connection using `manageconnection(false).`  The problem I'm having is that after the dbC.Close statement the connection to the DB never drops so I just accumulate connections until the max hits at 104 and then I get a connection error.  I have tried to add `dbC.dispose, dbC = Nothing` and nothing in that else statement for `CloseConnection seems to matter.`  The connections remains open.  I'm wondering if it's because I'm passing my msr into `dbExecute ByRef`, so it's holding the connection open for that dataset?  If so how can I work around getting my DataReader passed back to the calling procedure?  I'm trying to manage me DB connections after each DB call, but currently not doing a good job at it!  Hope another set of eyes can help me understand my problem.

I'm using the following as an example of how I call the DB connection now:
Public Class frmLogin

```
Dim db As New DBCon
Dim msr As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
Dim Query As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckConn.Click
    Query = "Select username from db.userstable"
    db.dbExecute(Query, msr)
```

******The following is the Module code****************

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class DBCon

```
Dim dbC As MySqlConnection

Public Sub ManageConnection(ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean)
    Try
        dbC = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=****; password=****; database=****;")
        If CloseConnection = True Then
            If dbC.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then _
                dbC.Open()
        Else
            dbC.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("DB Connection failure:" & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub dbExecute(ByVal q As String, ByRef msr As MySqlDataReader)
    Try
        ManageConnection(True) 'Open connection'

        Dim msc As New MySqlCommand(q, dbC)
        msr = msc.ExecuteReader

        ManageConnection(False) 'Close connection'

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Tried users suggestions below and was still seeing a connection hang when looking at the mysql workbench-performance-client connections.  So I changed my ManageConnection code to the following below just to test and called it directly as :dbCon.ManageConnection (true) and as soon as the .open line fires I see a new connection to mysql, but the .close, .dispose and =nothing lines do not clear out that connection.  Do I have something set wrong in mysql?  If .open creates a new connection, I'm not sure why the very next line of .close wouldn't get rid of it.  I do believe that's the root of my problem though.  Hopefully someone has run into this before.  Let me know your thoughts.

```
    Public Sub ManageConnection(ByVal CloseConnection As Boolean)
    Try
        If CloseConnection = True Then
            dbC = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=****; password=****; database=dbname;")
            dbC.Open()
            dbC.Close()
            dbC.Dispose()
            dbC = Nothing
        Else
            dbC.Close()
            dbC.Dispose()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("DB Connection failure:" & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Anyone else have any ideas?  If I can't make the connection close I guess I will just try and open it once when the program opens and hold it open until the program closes.  I felt I could do better than that though and still separate the code out into modules/classes so the DB calls were short in the middle of other code. Even if you can't answer this original question I'd be open to how you are handling your DB open's and closes with mysql.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to cope with these database connection leaks. [`Using  ...  End Using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.100).aspx) is probably the best. But you can also do `dbC.Dispose()` or `set dbC = Nothing` when you're done with a connection object.

The point is to, without fail, `Dispose()` the connection object when you're done with it.  `Using` does that for you even if your program hits exceptions.

Try something like this in your main program. And stop using that `ManageConnection` sub. It's practically guaranteed to leak connections.

```
 Using dbC as New MySqlConnection("server=localhost; userid=****; password=****; database=****;")

     Dim msc As New MySqlCommand(q, dbC)
     msr = msc.ExecuteReader     

    ...

End Using
```

Comment: I completely agree with using Using.  I was looking at the ManageConnection Sub and with the New MySqlConnection line outside of the If statement it makes a new connection, even when you're trying to close the open connection.  So those just seem to stack on top of each other (I hit my 256 limit with SqlCeConnections with the original code).  By moving the New MySqlConnection into the If statement when CloseConnection = true, it should work as expected.  But again, I would still use Using instead.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion..  the only issues with this is that when I call the dbC.open I intend on using it from the calling Sub dbExecute and so when you return to that sub and hit this line: Dim msc As New MySqlCommand(q, dbC) the dbC is no longer a valid connection.  AND it still is showing as a lingering connection in the mysql dashboard which I also don't understand.

Comment: Capellan I will try your suggestion here in an hour or so and let you know.  Makes a whole lot of sense what you are saying.

Comment: I added a new directly called code snippet above where I only call into the .open portion of my DB connection and directly after call a .close and .dispose and = nothing and none of those release the connection when looking at the mysql workbench client connections.